# Запрет на нажатие кнопки

Tags: javascript

Если появляется сообщение

```
<span id="error-msg" class="">Неверный номер</span>
```

То запретить нажатие на кнопку

```
<button type="submit" id="button3509871" class="btn f-btn  button-md btn-success" >
    Зарегистрироваться бесплатно</button>
```

id кнопки постоянно новый генерируется, так что к нему прицепиться не выходи, но классы постоянные. 
id и классы у span постоянные
Думал может как то к количеству символов в span привязаться, так как элемент изначально пустой, но если введен неверный номер, там появляются разного рода ошибки (номер короткий, длинный и т.д.)

Comment: Если у вас нет чёткого условия, то не понятно как решать задачу. Есть хоть что-то особенного кроме того, что это спан? Если нет, то цепляться к любому спану, или создать хоть какое-то отличие.

Comment: Повесьте стабильный id на родительский элемент кнопки, тогда её можно будет достать через `document.querySelector('#my-id button[type="submit"]').disabled = true;`

Comment: имеется ввиду id кнопки,а классы там постоянные. У span id и class всегда одинаковый

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так (адаптируйте под вашу ситуацию, это просто заготовка):

```
let btn = document.querySelector('button');
let msgParent = document.querySelector('.parent-class'); // внутри этого блока сообщения
let observer = new MutationObserver(()=>{
    if( !msgParent.querySelector('.error-msg') ) return;
    btn.disabled = true;
});
observer.observe( msgParent, { childList: true });
```

Comment: let msgParent = document.querySelector('.parent-class');   от какого елемента этот класс, не очень понимаю

Comment: вместо parent-class селектор блока, в котором сообщения появляются (первый родитель)

Comment: не работает. тут глянуть можете http://514.weborob-it.com/

Comment: там столько всего, что не могу найти скрипт. сделайте пример аналогичный где всё просто, а не куча всего. И что именно не работает? на каком шаге ошибка?

Comment: http://joxi.ru/823R8ybtDb49Qm

Comment: кнопка не блокируется, если появляется сообщение о неверном номере

Comment: Я спросил на каком шаге ошибка, а вы отвечаете просто не работает. Находится ли btn вы проверили? находится ли msgParent? Срабатывает ли обзёрвер?

Comment: ну я ошибок по консоли не наблюдаю, а как проверить то что вы написали выше, увы не знаю

Comment: Я вот подумал, что может передать кнопке disable, если в span пропадает класс hide ?